Is it possible to implement smtp Oauth2 without generation application or without client id and client secret

I Want to implement SMTP Oauth2  without generation application or without client id and client secret.
Does it possible ?

I have username and password based on that can i get token and implement Oauth2?



Implementing SMTP OAuth2 authentication typically requires using a client ID and client secret. These credentials are part of the OAuth2 framework, which is designed to provide authorization without sharing password details, by obtaining an access token from the authorization server.

Then how Thunderbird works for auth2 because it only ask  for username

Thunderbird and similar email clients support OAuth2 for email accounts (such as Gmail, Outlook, etc.) without explicitly asking the user for a client ID or client secret. This works because the email client itself is registered with the email service provider as an OAuth2 client.
